# How to find Guava Public Suffix Version

Tags: java, guava

How can I find the Public Suffix List version [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) is using? Is there a command to see the version when I have the package installed? Or is there some note in the release notes I am missing?

I see that they use Mozilla Foundation's [Public Suffix List](http://publicsuffix.org/) but this list seems to update much more frequently than Guava releases. Does Guava pull the latest every time they do a release? This question I hope to answer once I know where to find the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't document which version we're using. But you can look at [`PublicSuffixPatterns` at some release tag](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v30.1.1/guava/src/com/google/thirdparty/publicsuffix/PublicSuffixPatterns.java) and follow the link to the commit that updated it most recently. That should tell you approximately how old the data is.

Traditionally, we updated [about every 6 weeks](https://github.com/google/guava/commit/ef6283a97b7db54f15e312656584fd72ad70948d#diff-4b5a99bf87e7b696c60ce3240caf199a4a316604424016b58e0aa9e6b9117b0b), and [the file history](https://github.com/google/guava/commits/master/guava/src/com/google/thirdparty/publicsuffix/PublicSuffixPatterns.java) suggests that that's still approximately correct.

Ideally someday we'll provide [a way for users to regenerate the patterns file themselves](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1123), but we haven't yet.

Answer (score 1):

you can see that guava uses it's own sort of engine to acknowledge theses values, but it's engine is well documented [Here](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/thirdparty/publicsuffix/PublicSuffixPatterns.java)